# MouseWheel Trace Works in Debug Mode, not Test

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is my code in its entirety. It won't trace when I Test Movie, but when I debug, it works fine.

```
import flash.events.*;

function scrollWheelHandler(e:MouseEvent){
    trace(e.delta);
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, scrollWheelHandler);
```

I hate flash. This is in a new project btw. wtf is going on?

Answer (score 0):

MouseWheel events don't register with Flash Player on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

There're some libraries to support failure of MouseWheel events on Mac.

SWFWheel is one of it and widely used by Japanese ActionScript communities.
http://www.libspark.org/wiki/SWFWheel/en

This uses Javascript to detect MouseWheel events via ExternalInterface.